# What installer to choose for 64-bit GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, download

I want to install 64-bit Monero GUI, but the [Monero downloads page](https://web.getmonero.org/downloads/) shows both a "Windows, 64-bit" and "Windows, 64-bit Installer" option.

What is the difference on these two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of them is a portable zip file, the other is an installer that will install Monero onto your computer. The installer is likely an easier option for beginner/intermediate users.

Comment: Thanks.  Btw, why is there different SW on https://web.getmonero.org/downloads/ and https://monero.org/downloads/ ?  What is the "right" place to download from?

Comment: No one knows who runs [monero.org](https://monero.org/), but they host old downloads to the pre-ASIC resistant network.

Comment: Monero[dot]org is possessed by a domain squatter. Thus, make sure to avoid it.